# Play Audio Simultaneously

Tags: node.js, audio, websocket, socket.io, nodejs-stream

I want to stream audio from NodeJS server to a client browser using socket.io and socket.io-stream and I did it successfully and have only one problem.
First of all, this is the code
server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const port = process.env.port || 8080;

const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
const ss = require("socket.io-stream");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${port}`);
});

io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.emit("start", { hello: "world!" });
  socket.on("stream", data => {
    let stream = ss.createStream();
    let filename = path.join(__dirname, `/clips/Wegz.mp3`);

    ss(socket).emit("audio-stream", stream, { name: filename });
    fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(stream);
  });
});
```

client.js

```
var socket = io("http://localhost:" + window.location.port);
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

socket.on("start", function(data) {
  socket.emit("stream", { Data: "you can send any data back" });
  ss(socket).on("audio-stream", function(stream, data) {
    let parts = [];
    stream.on("data", chunk => {
      parts.push(chunk);
    });
    stream.on("end", function() {
      console.log(i);
      audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(parts));
      audio.play();
    });
  });
});
```

the problem here is that I play the audio after all chunks are pushed to the list BUT I want to play audio simultaneously chunk by chunk without waiting for all parts to be pushed.
I hope I clarified my question and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

did you try doing this?
    `stream.on("data", chunk => {`
    `audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(parts));`
    `audio.play();`
    `parts.push(chunk);`
    `});`

Comment: I tried to do it but it plays so fast so all chunks are overlapping and finally it plays the whole track at the end so the result is nearly the same as the above code.

Comment: may be you can check if audio.src has value or not, if it has value then play the audio & on data method just add the chunk in audio.src, don't overwrite.